# IndexRedirect only if segment is not already defined?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this simple app:

```
// index.js

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, IndexRedirect, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import A from './a'
import B from './b'

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/foo' component={A}>
            <IndexRedirect to='1' />
            <Route path=':bar' component={B} />
         </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

When I'm at `/foo/3`, if I click on a link that points to `/foo/` I get redirected to `/foo/1`.

Is there an easy way to make the `IndexRedirect` redirect to the already in use `segment` instead of the default one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use browserHistory listener

```
browserHistory.listen(function(ev) {
    console.log('listen', ev.pathname.split('/'));
     var pathData = ev.pathname.split('/'); 
});
```

and replace your `<IndexRedirect to='1' />` to whatever you want
for example:

```
var defaultIndex = 1
browserHistory.listen(function(ev) {
    console.log('listen', ev.pathname.split('/'));
    var pathData = ev.pathname.split('/');
    defaultIndex = pathData[1]
});
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/foo' component={A}>
        <IndexRedirect to={defaultIndex} />
        <Route path=':bar' component={B} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

this works for me.

Comment: Thanks, my Router is rendered directly by react-dom.render, the `defaultIndex` variable seems to not get updated in the router when the route changes (the listener is called, but the value in the router doesn't get updated).

Comment: Moving the router inside a component, I can properly update the `to` value, but I get `You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored`